# problems of memory manager in matlab and C

Tags: c, matlab, memory-leaks, mex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [memory allocation in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564224/memory-allocation-in-matlab)

I was searching for solving a memory leak problem in C project which calls a DLL generated from MATLAB, and I found this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42564). Are what is written in that link is true? Can any one explain it in some details?

My memory leak problem in some details is when I call a function in the dll for the first tile in a loop, every thing is great, for the rest some amount of memory is leak and it is **not accumulate** for example:- before calling the function for the fist one memory has `2000 MB` free for the second time it has `1800 MB` free. It is reasonable to be `1600 MB` after the third calling, but it is still **`1800 MB`** free and still `1800 MB` for the rest of the program. why it is not increasing !!

I am using windows 7 x86 as an OS, MatLab 2011a, Thank you

Comment: What was the dll, the function, and how are you using it?

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry: the link in the closed duplicate question

Comment: The last four questions you have asked have been closed.  You might want to review the site [faq] before you get banned.

Comment: After copying the question and posting it, I deleted the previous one. But It didn't be deleted. So i am very sorry.

I read the faq and I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure the memory leak is within the library? Do you know what the library function is doing?

There are [examples of non-cumulative memory leaks from calling dlopen/dlclose](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/883775) (in other OSs, but still)